# How to change background color of inset figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create an inset figure that has a different projection from the parent.  The only issue I have at this point is the inset figures's tick labels are not legible because they are black and blend in with the plot behind it.  I could change the color of the ticks and labels to white, but that does not help when the data in `ax0` yields lighter colors.  Here is the MWE:

```
import calipsoFunctions as cf
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl


from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes, mark_inset, InsetPosition

x, y = np.arange(100), np.arange(200)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
C = np.random.randint(0, 100, (200, 100))

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(6.5, 5.25))
gs0 = pl.GridSpec(3, 1)
gs0.update(left=0.08, right=0.925,
           top=0.95, bottom=0.33,
           hspace=0.10, wspace=0.0)

gs1 = pl.GridSpec(1, 2)
gs1.update(left=0.08, right=0.925,
           top=0.225, bottom=0.05,
           hspace=0.0, wspace=0.025)

# create primary axes
ax0 = pl.subplot(gs0[0])
ax1 = pl.subplot(gs0[1])


ax0.pcolormesh(X, Y, C, vmin=0, vmax=75)
ax1.pcolormesh(X, Y, C, vmin=0, vmax=75)

# add map plot (inset axis)
loc_box = [0.8, 0.55, 0.20, 0.45]
ax0_inset = fig.add_axes(loc_box,
                         projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                         aspect="auto",
                         facecolor="w",
                         frameon=True)

lat_array = np.arange(-20, 20)
lon_array = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.5)

ax0_inset.plot(lat_array, lon_array, "k-", lw=1)

ip = InsetPosition(ax0, loc_box)
ax0_inset.set_axes_locator(ip)

ax0_inset.coastlines(resolution="10m", linewidth=0.25, color="k")
ax0_inset.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)

llat, ulat = lat_array.min(), lat_array.max()
llon, ulon = lon_array.min(), lon_array.max()

llat = np.round(llat / 10) * 10
ulat = np.round(ulat / 10) * 10
llon = np.round(llon / 5) * 5
ulon = np.round(ulon / 5) * 5

ax0_inset.set_yticks(np.arange(llat, ulat, 20), minor=False)
ax0_inset.set_yticks(np.arange(llat, ulat, 10), minor=True)
ax0_inset.set_yticklabels(np.arange(llat, ulat, 20),
                          fontsize=8)
ax0_inset.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LatitudeFormatter())

ax0_inset.set_xticks(np.arange(llon, ulon, 5), minor=False)
ax0_inset.set_xticks(np.arange(llon, ulon, 1), minor=True)
ax0_inset.set_xticklabels(np.arange(llon, ulon, 5),
                          fontsize=8,
                          rotation=45)
ax0_inset.xaxis.set_major_formatter(LongitudeFormatter())

ax0_inset.grid()
ax0_inset.tick_params(which="both",
                      axis="both",
                      direction="in",
                      labelsize=8)

fig.show()
```

Is there a way to change the background color of `ax0_inset` so that these tick labels are legible?  I tried changing the face_color to `"w"`, but that did not work.  Ideally, I want the same behavior as `ax0.figure.set_facecolor("w")`, but for the `ax0_inset` axis.  Is this doable?

Comment: FYI: ["Since heavily importing into the global namespace may result in unexpected behavior, the use of pylab is strongly discouraged. Use matplotlib.pyplot instead."](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab)

Comment: I would not know how to change the color just around an axis object (does it even have a color? is it not just transparent?) but to imitate the expected behavior, you can place a (semitransparent) rectangle patch of the desired color directly under the axis inset object using the same loc_box coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Mr. T's comment suggestion, a work-around solution could be:

```
# insert transparent (or opaque) rectangle around inset_axes plot 
# to make axes labels more visible

# make buffer variable to control amount of buffer around inset_axes
buffer = 0.1 # fractional axes coordinates

# use ax inset tuple coords in loc_box to add rectangle patch
# [left, bottom, width, height] (fractional axes coordinates)
fig.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((
    loc_box[0]-buffer, loc_box[1]-buffer), 
    loc_box[2]+buffer, loc_box[3]+buffer, 
    linestyle="-", edgecolor="k", facecolor="w", 
    linewidth=1, alpha=0.75, zorder=5, 
    transform=ax0.transAxes))
```